# how to search with three form fields in elastic search using jest client or transport client

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

three form fields means experience and skills and location i want search with skills or skills with location or skills with experience ..but here skills is mandiatory..i write only search with skills but i want search with differently like mentioned above pls help me

here i search skills ..code

// Client class

```
public class ElasticClient 
{
private static JestClient client = null;

private ElasticClient(){

}

public static JestClient getClient()
{
    String clusterIP = "localhost";
    String port = "9200";

    //setup client
    JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
            .Builder("http://" + clusterIP + ":" + port)
            .multiThreaded(true)
            .build());
    JestClient client = factory.getObject();

    return client;
   }

}
```

//model class

```
 package com.elastic.model;
 import io.searchbox.annotations.JestId;
 public class SearchModel {
 @JestId
 private String _id;
 private String CurrentJobTitles;
 private String Experience;
 private String skills;

public SearchModel(String _id, String currentJobTitles, String experience,
        String skills) {
    super();
    this._id = _id;
    CurrentJobTitles = currentJobTitles;
    Experience = experience;
    this.skills = skills;
}

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getCurrentJobTitles() {
    return CurrentJobTitles;
}

public void setCurrentJobTitles(String currentJobTitles) {
    CurrentJobTitles = currentJobTitles;
}


public String getExperience() {
    return Experience;
}

public void setExperience(String experience) {
    Experience = experience;
}

public String getSkills() {
    return skills;
}


public void setSkills(String skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}


@Override
  public String toString() {
  return  
  "_id='" + _id + '\'' + 
  ", CurrentJobTitles='" + CurrentJobTitles + '\'' +
  ", Experience='" + Experience + '\'' +
  ", skills='" + skills + '\''

   ;

  }
  }
```

//controller class

```
 @Controller
 public class SearchController {    

 @RequestMapping(value = "/doSearch.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public List<SearchModel> getMessages(@RequestParam("skills") String   skills, Model model)
 {
 System.out.println(skills);
 SearchResource search = new SearchResource();
 List<SearchModel> list = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();
 list = search.searchCouple(searchKey);
 System.out.println(list);
 model.addAttribute("list",list);
 return list;
}
}
```

// service class

```
public List<SearchModel> searchCouple(String skills)
{
    List<SearchModel> list = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();
    JestClient client = ElasticClient.getClient();


    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+skills+"*"));


    Search search = (Search) new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString())
    .addIndex("eix")
    .addType("articles")
    .build();

    try 
    {
        SearchResult result = client.execute(search);
        List<SearchResult.Hit<SearchModel, Void>> list1 = result.getHits(SearchModel.class);

        if(!list1.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++)
            {
                Hit<SearchModel, Void> p = list1.get(i);
                SearchModel e = p.source;
                list.add(e);
                System.out.println(list);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        client.shutdownClient();
    }

    return list;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you want only skills:

```
GET /hotlist/candidate/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "skills",
                            "query": "java,html"
                    }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So in Java API should be:

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"));
```

If you want skills and JobLocations:

```
GET /hotlist/candidate/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "skills",
                            "query": "java,html"
                    }
               },
               {
                   "term": {
                      "JobLocations": {
                         "value": "hyd"
                      }
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In Java API:

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"))
      .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("JobLocations", jobLocations))
      );
```

If you want all:

```
GET /hotlist/candidate/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "skills",
                            "query": "java,html"
                    }
               },
               {
                   "term": {
                      "JobLocations": {
                         "value": "hyd"
                      }
                   }
               },
               {
                   "term": {
                      "Experience": {
                         "value": "1"
                      }
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In Java API:

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"))
      .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("JobLocations", jobLocations))
      .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Experience", experience))
      );
```

So you should have something like:

```
public List<SearchModel> searchCouple(String skills, String experience, String location)
{
    List<SearchModel> list = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();
    JestClient client = ElasticClient.getClient();


    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(experience)) {
      if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(location)) {
        //location and experience are present
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("JobLocations", jobLocations))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Experience", experience))
                );
      } else {
        //Only experience is present
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Experience", experience))
                );
      }
    } else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(location)) {
      //Only location is present
      searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"))
                .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("JobLocations", jobLocations))
                );

    } else {
      //Neither location and experience are present
      searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(skills).defaultField("skills"))
                );
    }

   //[...]
```

Comment: i am not getting results  
i am getting [](null) value

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your type ?

Comment: like {   "hotlist": {"aliases": {}, "mappings": { "candidate": {"properties":{ "CurrentJobTitles":"type":"string"},"Experience":"type":"string"},,"JobLocations": {"type":"string"},"achievement":{"type": "string" },"city":{"type":"string"},"country":"type":"string"},"hotlist":"properties":"aliases":"type":"object"},"mappings": {"properties": {"candidate": {"properties": {"properties": {"properties":Experience":{"properties":{"type": {"type":"string" }}},

Comment: can i post the total service class couls u fix it ,,again i am getting null values

Answer (score 0):

Use `bool query` as defined below.

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(experience) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(location))

        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+skills+"*")).
                must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+experience+"*").defaultOperator("AND"))
        .must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+location+"*").defaultOperator("AND")));

    else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(experience))

    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+skills+"*")).
            must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+experience+"*").defaultOperator("AND")));
    else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(location))

        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+skills+"*")).
                must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+location+"*").defaultOperator("AND")));
    else
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.queryString("*"+skills+"*")));
```

Comment: i am not getting results

Comment: Share the mapping please

Comment: i am getting [](null) value

Comment: I want you to share the mappings. GET/index/type/_mapping

Comment: hotlist is index and type is candidate

Comment: I want to know mapping of fields. Mapping looks like :{
"so3":{
"mappings":{
"so3":{
"properties":{
"day":{
"type":"long"
},
"doc_as_upsert":{
"type":"boolean"
},
"name":{
"type":"string"
},
"searchengine":{
"type":"string"
},
"socialnetwork":{
"type":"string"
},
"tier":{
"type":"string"
}
}
}
}
}
}

Comment: like {   "hotlist": {"aliases": {}, "mappings": { "candidate": {"properties":{ "CurrentJobTitles":"type":"string"},"Experience":"type":"string"},,"JobLocations": {"type":"string"},"achievement":{"type": "string" },"city":{"type":"string"},"country":"type":"string"},"hotlist":"properties":"aliases":"type":"object"},"mappings": {"properties": {"candidate": {"properties": {"properties": {"properties":Experience":{"properties":{"type": {"type":"string" }}},

Comment: Share the document which you expect to be matched with above query.

Comment: when i work with one field its working fine but searching with three fields i am not able code ..POST /hotlist/candidate/
{   
      "FirstName": "raja",
      "LastName": "S",
      "CurrentJobTitles": "java deloper",
      "SuitableJobTitles": "HADOOP ",
      "city": "hyderabad",
      "state": "ts",
      "country": "india",
      "ZipCode": "500078",
      "JobLocations": "hyd",
      "skills": "java,javascript,html,xml,rest,elastic",
      "achievement": "no",
      "Experience": "1 YEAR",
      "tagline": "java developer and elastic developer",
      "IndustryExperience": "IT"
   }

Comment: As mentioned above in your document, experience field has value "1 YEAR". So answer mentioned above wont work as I have used term query which works for analyzed fields(exact term). I have updated my answer. Verify if it works for you

Comment: ok thank you but i need ur help when i enter exp as like 0 to 99 i mean two fields like price range ..could u write code for that.

Comment: Your format for experience is not fixed. Some documents have value like 1YEAR ,some like 0 to 99. For range query to work you need to have 2 different fields . You might have to change the structure of your index for this to work.